# Spring Boot with Spring Security returns 404 on valid login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When I activate Spring Security trough custom bean `@PreAuthorize("@mySecurity.check(#car)")` valid requests (check returns true) will end up in 404, and invalid requests will end up in 200. Without the PreAuthorize all works fine.

The authorisation is done via JWT, and the granted authorities are set correctly.

When I step through the debugger, the PreAuthorize check works correctly returning true or false.

I have the following enabled:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

The Rest controller implements the Method with the following annotation

```
    @PreAuthorize("@mySecurity.check(#car)")
    public List<Driver> getAllVersions(String car) {
```

A Request without security check would look like

```
2019-09-30 13:34:22.306 DEBUG 26204 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2019-09-30 13:34:42.042 DEBUG 26204 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/car/foobar", parameters={}
...
2019-09-30 13:34:42.049 DEBUG 26204 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-09-30 13:34:42.050 DEBUG 26204 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [{
  "id": "hi",
  "name": "hi",
  "isActive": false
}]
2019-09-30 13:34:42.052 DEBUG 26204 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

When activating PreAuthorize and doing a valid request, it seems to work partial.

```
2019-09-30 13:44:22.597 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/car/foobar", parameters={}
...
2019-09-30 13:44:28.912 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected '*/*' given [*/*]
2019-09-30 13:44:28.938 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name '/api/v1/car/foobar2', model {configurationVersionList=[{
  "id": "bar",
  "name": "bar",
  "isActive": false
}, {
  "id": "foo",
  "name": "foo",
  "isActive": false
}]}
2019-09-30 13:44:28.946 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [api/v1/car/foobar2]
2019-09-30 13:44:28.950 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/api/v1/car/foobar2/api/v1/car/foobar2", parameters={}
2019-09-30 13:44:28.959 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-09-30 13:44:28.963 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-09-30 13:44:28.963 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2019-09-30 13:44:28.970 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-09-30 13:44:28.981 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-09-30 13:44:28.984 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-09-30 13:44:29.000 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-09-30 13:44:29.001 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Sep 30 13:44:28 CEST 2019, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, (truncated)...]
2019-09-30 13:44:29.027 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

If I do an not allowed Request, I receive a 200:

```
2019-09-30 13:45:53.514 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/car/%7Bfoobar%7D", parameters={}
...
2019-09-30 13:45:55.660 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-09-30T11:45:55.660Z, principal=JohnDoe, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details={... snip ...}]
2019-09-30 13:45:55.661 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Zugriff verweigert
```

pom.xml

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Security  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

As requested:

```
@Component
public class MySecurity {

    public boolean check(String car) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<String> givenpermissions = auth.getAuthorities().stream().map(x -> (GrantedAuthority) x)
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).filter(authority -> authority.startsWith("car-holder-"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return !givenpermissions.isEmpty();
    }


}
```

The endpoint should just verify the JWT (working), ensure the permissions and then return a json answer.

I've currently now Idea what the issue could be, so any approach is welcome..

**SOLUTION**

removed the interface

Comment: what does `@mySecurity.check(#car)` do?

Comment: returning true or false depending on permission in jwt. I'v added it - As described, this seems to wrok fine (debugger approved).

Comment: Can you post the Spring security Configuration?

Comment: 404 means your URL is bad: server not found. Check that first.  Turn off security and make sure you can access the service.

Comment: Hi @duffymo as mentioned in the text, it works without security.

Comment: Then check the URL with security.  What does Fiddler tell you when you turn it on?

Comment: as mentioned above, 404 on valid requests and 200 on invalid requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is your Controller annotated with `@RestController`? if not you'll need `@ResponseBody`
annotation on your method

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurity.check(#car)")
@ResponseBody
public List<Driver> getAllVersions(String car) {
```

Without this spring tries to load the actual view which is not present - 404

Or missing PathParam annotation

```
public List<Driver> getAllVersions(@PathParam("ParamName") String car)
```

I had some issues in the past with annotations on implemented interfaces instead on the class directly. PreAuthorize does some extra "magic", just an idea

Comment: its annotated with @RestController, adding response body hasn't changed anything

Comment: @MemLeak did you try `public List<Driver> getAllVersions(@PathParam("ParamName") String car)` ?

Comment: I've `@PathVariable`in the interface - with debuging, I reach the method, error occurs after returning the list...

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.8 (Spring 5.1.9) - But I doen't really get the relation between the path variable and the response - as its working when removing @PreAuthorize

Comment: some log entries are strange `2019-09-30 13:44:28.946 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [api/v1/car/foobar2]
2019-09-30 13:44:28.950 DEBUG 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/api/v1/car/foobar2/api/v1/car/foobar2", parameters={}
...` I had some issues in the past with annotations on implemented interfaces instead on the class directly. PreAuthorize does some extra "magic", just an idea

Answer (score 0):

try to put @ResponeBody for the method in controller class

Comment: can you put the code with formatting ? it will be more clear, from this answer its not understandable to put that to which method.